# Dirichlet and Neumann problems uniqueness

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> Prove uniqueness for the Dirichlet and Neumann problems for the reduced Helmholtz
>   equation $\triangle u − ku = 0$ in a bounded planar domain $D$, where $k$ is a positive constant.

How can I prove this? I found that Green’s third identity to be useful in proving this but I am not sure how to apply it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Green's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_identities#Green.27s_first_identity) says that 
$$\int_D(f\Delta f+|\nabla f|^2)=\int_{\partial\Omega}f\frac{\partial f}{\partial \nu}.$$
Now take $f=u$ and by the assumption that $\Delta u-ku=0$ in $D$, we have 
$$\int_D(ku^2+|\nabla u|^2)=\int_{\partial\Omega}u\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}.$$
Dirichlet boundary condition says that $u=0$ on $\partial\Omega$, and Nerumann boundary condition says that $\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}=0$ on $\partial\Omega$. In either case, 
we have 
$$\int_{\partial\Omega}u\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}=0.$$
Combining all these, we have
$$\int_D(ku^2+|\nabla u|^2)=0.$$ 
Since $k$ is positive by assumption, we have $u\equiv 0$.

Comment: Thank you very much! It is much more clear to me now.